# ServiceStack - calling 3rd party web service with class

Tags: api, url, servicestack

I am trying to call a 3rd party web service

Their REST API uses the following URL style.

```
http://www.VoiceBase.com/services?version=1.0&apikey=your-apikey&password=secret&action=list&status=processing
```

All of their service calls go to the same /services

How do I create a class so the following would work?

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://www.voicebase.com");
var response = client.Get<ResponseVoiceBaseListClass>(new VoiceBaseListClass());
```

Additional classes I have created but I am not quite there yet

```
    public class VoiceBaseBaseClass
    {
        public string version { get; set; }
        public string apikey { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }

        public VoiceBaseBaseClass()
        {
            this.version = "1.0";
            this.apikey = "API";
            this.password = "password";
        }
    }

    public class VoiceBaseListClass : VoiceBaseBaseClass, IReturn<ResponseVoiceBaseListClass>
    {
        public string action { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }

        public VoiceBaseListClass()
            : base()
        {
            this.action = "list";
            this.status = "processing";
        }
    }


    public class ResponseVoiceBaseListClass
    {
        public string requestStatus { get; set; }
        public string statusMessage { get; set; }
        public string fileStatus { get; set; }
        public List<string> mediaIds { get; set; }

        public ResponseVoiceBaseListClass()
        {
            this.mediaIds = new List<string>();
        }
    }
```

Using the above classes the call that goes to the server is

```
/json/syncreply/VoiceBaseListClass?action=list&status=processing&version=1.0&apikey=API&Password=password
```

Is there a way I can force the service stack client to go to the

```
 /Services
```

instead of

```
/json/syncreply/VoiceBaseListClass
```

Comment: I think you probably can mould this to work for you.  My understanding is that the JsonServiceClient is designed to make it easy to connect to other ServiceStack services. It does this, by using the ServiceStack conventions (hence it's connecting to /json/syncreply/...). You are trying to use it to connect to a 3rd party api. AFAIK this is not what the class was designed for. I think you'd be better off writing your own class to manage connecting to this third party api (unless they have their own one).  I could be wrong - but it looks very ServiceStack orientated.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this and it is working great for me.

```
    [RestService("/services", "GET")]
    public class VoiceBaseListClass : VoiceBaseBaseClass, IReturn<ResponseVoiceBaseListClass>
    {
    }
```

Although this is a deprecated attribute - the new attribute is called Route

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Release-Notes

Chris